# Copy multiple tables result to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powershell

I have a massive SQL query that returns 4 tables. I'm able to return the first table but not the other tables here is the code I'm using below. I'm using a powershell script that I found online. I was about to get the second table by changing `$DataSetTable = $DataSet.Tables[0]` to `$DataSetTable = $DataSet.Tables[1]`  the second table was return in the excel sheet but not the first one.

How can I all the tables?

```bsh
$SQLServer = 'SQLCL01'
$Database = 'home'
$SqlQuery = @' Query goes here'@

## - Connect to SQL Server using non-SMO class 'System.Data':
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

## - Extract and build the SQL data object '$DataSetTable':
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSetTable = $DataSet.Tables[0]

## --------- Working with Excel ------- ##

## - Create an Excel Application instance:
$xlsObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

## - Create new Workbook and Sheet (Visible = 1 / 0 not visible)
$xlsObj.Visible = 1
$xlsWb = $xlsobj.Workbooks.Add()
$xlsSh = $xlsWb.Worksheets.item(1)

$xlsSh = $xlsWb.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
$xlsSh.Name = "Back date dump"
$xlsSh = $xlsWb.ActiveSheet

## - Build the Excel column heading:
[Array] $getColumnNames = $DataSetTable.Columns | Select ColumnName

## - Build column header:
[int] $RowHeader = 1
foreach ($ColH in $getColumnNames) {
  $xlsSh.Cells.item(1, $RowHeader).font.bold = $true
  $xlsSh.Cells.item(1, $RowHeader) = $ColH.ColumnName
  $RowHeader++
}

## - Adding the data start in row 2 column 1:
[int] $rowData = 2
[int] $colData = 1

foreach ($rec in $DataSetTable.Rows) {
  foreach ($Coln in $getColumnNames) {
    ## - Next line convert cell to be text only:
    $xlsSh.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"

    ## - Populating columns:
    $xlsSh.Cells.Item($rowData, $colData) = $rec.$($Coln.ColumnName).ToString()
    $ColData++
  }
  $rowData++; $ColData = 1
}

## - Adjusting columns in the Excel sheet:
$xlsRng = $xlsSH.usedRange
$xlsRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
```

Comment: So, `$DataSetTable1 = $DataSet.Tables[0];` then `$DataSetTable2 = $DataSet.Tables[1];` and so on, and then paste the various tables into different sheets.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician that's a great idea!! Instead of different sheets, ideally I want the data to be in the same sheets. I think I'm going have to change the script where I'm building the excel sheet some way

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all tables in the collection:

```
$xlsObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
foreach ($DataSetTable in $DataSet.Tables) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: @thanks loop is a better idea but I added the loop and I'm not getting any results back on the excel. here is what i added. can you help me with this?  `foreach ($DataSetTable in $DataSet.Tables) {                    "$DataSetTable = " + $DataSetTable                    }`

Comment: What is `"$DataSetTable = " + $DataSetTable` supposed to achieve?

Comment: i'm not sure if i was using the syntax correctly. i was use this Syntax as a reference `ForEach (item In collection) {ScriptBlock}`